# JavaScript Split without losing character

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split certain text using JavaScript. The text looks like:

```
9:30 pm
The user did action A.

10:30 pm
Welcome, user John Doe.

11:30 am
Messaged user John Doe
```

Now, I want to split the string into events. i.e.:

```
9:30 pm
The user did action A.
```

would be one event. I'm using RegEx for this:

```
var split = journals.split(/\d*\d:/);
```

Thing is, the first two characters are getting lost. The split appears like this:

```
30 pm
    The user did action A.
```

How do I split so that the split maintains the first two/three characters (ie **9:** or **10:**) etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason that you don't want to split on double newline?

Comment: Yep, please see the reply to Vivin's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a lookahead:

```
var split = journals.split(/(?=\b\d+:)/);
```

Comment: Did you test it? This was the first I tested, but to my surprise it splitted between `\d*` and `\d` as well (ending up in 5 elements).

Comment: @BalusC: no, I was in a bit of a hurry (I'm in the middle of making dinner).  I've split on "non-characters" before using lookaheads though.

Comment: This actually works. Thanks so much!

(possible error could be my initial regex isn't perfect, I added the last \d* later on.

Comment: @BalusC, @Rohan: fixed the regex using a word boundary `\b`

Comment: Drat, I *knew* it. Good find, Andy :)

Comment: @Rohan: I should have addressed you first in my previous comment, I don't think it would alert both you and @BalusC.  I fixed the regex for you using a word boundary.

Comment: @Andy E's head -  if you could help out with this too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047594/javascript-split-with-regex

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to split on the newline?

```
var split = journals.split(/\n\n/);
```

**EDIT**

Try normalizing the string into a format that you can use:

```
/*
 Non-normalized string
*/
var str = "9:30 pm\nThe user did action A.10:30 pm\nWelcome, user John Doe.\n\n\n11:30 am\nMessaged user John Doe\n12:30 pm\nThe user did something else.";

/*
 Normalizing into a specific format. TIMESTAMP\nDESCRIPTION\n\n.
 Then removing extraneous leading \n\n
*/

str = str.replace(/\n*([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} (a|p)m)\n*/g, "\n\n$1\n").replace(/^\n+/, "");

var events = str.split(/\n\n/);

/*
 The following should display an array of strings of the form:
 TIMESTAMP\nDESCRIPTION
*/
console.log(events); 

/*
 Loop through events and split on single newline to get timestamp and description
*/
for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
   var event = events[i];
   var eventData = event.split(/\n/);
   var time = eventData[0];
   var description = eventData[1];
   console.log(time, description);
}
```

Comment: Yep. Sometimes there's an extra newline, sometimes there are no newlines, sometimes users remove newlines. That's not an option, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Thing is, the input string itself doesn't assure that there even will be \n characters in the correct places.

Comment: @Rohan The regular expression ensures that it inserts the `\n` at the appropriate places (it looks  for a pattern resembling a timestamp that could be preceded and/or succeeded by 0 or many `\n`s). But I think you should go with Andy's solution. It's much easier.