# Javascript split with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I just asked a question about Regex, and received a great answer: [JavaScript Split without losing character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047201/javascript-split-without-losing-character)

Now, I have another question.

My current Regex looks like this:

```
var split = text.split(/(?=\w*\d*\d:\d\d)/);
```

Basically, I'm trying to split using the timestamps (eg -  9:30 or 10:30, the difference between them is the extra digit in the latter). How do I go about this?

Currently, if I have these two:

```
9:30 pm
The user did action A.

10:30 pm
Welcome, user John Doe.
```

The splits are :

```
9:30 pm
The user did action A.
----
1
----
0:30 pm
Welcome, user John Doe.
```

How do I add an optional check for the first character in the timestamp?

Thanks!

Comment: Browsers have all sorts of incompatibilities in the ways that split()  works when the argument is a regex. See this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047201/javascript-split-without-losing-character/3047274#3047274) to your other question, I fixed this problem in the regex by adding a word boundary:

```
var split = journals.split(/\s*(?=\b\d+:)/);
```

Updated it with `\s*` to strip out any unnecessary whitespace (but not the line breaks) too.  Result:

```
["9:30 pm    
The user did action A.", "10:30 pm  
Welcome, user John Doe.", "11:30 am
Messaged user John Doe"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var split = text.split(/(?=\w*[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{2})/);
```

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) is helpful for these tasks.

Comment: Which doesn't -- that pattern or the site? If you are using the site, you need to just put in the pattern, i.e. `(\w*\d*\d:\d\d)` will match the input you gave.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do to the text, but I do have a regex that hopefully can help match the times only.

```
\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} (am|pm)
```

The problem with your regex and andy's regex is that the * is greedy. It means zero or more matches, *as many times as possible.* Using {min,max} with the exact numbers you need will be more accurate and avoid the greedy *.

edit: Andy's does in fact work on that site he linked. And the * doesn't seem to be greedy. Does either pattern work for you?

Comment: `{min, max}` was the first thing I tried.  The real problem is the lookahead, it will look ahead and find `0:30` and split on that, instead of `10:30`.  Adding a required word boundary forces the lookahead to find where the "word" begins. +1 and welcome to Stack Overflow :-)