# javascript - array.split with lookahead

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following string:

```
'(POINT (10 5),POINT EMPTY,LINESTRING (5 6, 15 17, 8 9),LINESTRING EMPTY,POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON EMPTY,MULTIPOINT (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1),MULTIPOINT EMPTY,MULTILINESTRING ((5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9)),MULTILINESTRING EMPTY,MULTIPOLYGON (((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),, ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1))),MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY)',
```

I would like to split this into an array of strings, and the separator should be `),[A-Z]`. (so `),` followed by an uppercase letter)

But I also do not want to lose the separators.

After looking at this question: [JavaScript Split without losing character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047201/javascript-split-without-losing-character)

I tried:

```
let string = '(POINT (10 5),POINT EMPTY,LINESTRING (5 6, 15 17, 8 9),LINESTRING EMPTY,POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON EMPTY,MULTIPOINT (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1),MULTIPOINT EMPTY,MULTILINESTRING ((5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9)),MULTILINESTRING EMPTY,MULTIPOLYGON (((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),, ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1))),MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY)'
let stringArray = string.split(/(?=\),[A-Z]\)/);
```

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong? Is is the regex expression?

So the desired output would be:

```
['(POINT (10 5)',
'POINT EMPTY',
'POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1))',
'MULTIPOINT (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)',
'MULTIPOINT EMPTY',
...
]
```

Comment: Please write in your question the desired output.

Comment: @gabry sry, edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the methods how to solve it, would be using a positive lookahead `?=` and a non-capturing group `?:`.

And about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```js
let string = 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POINT (10 5),POINT EMPTY,LINESTRING (5 6, 15 17, 8 9),LINESTRING EMPTY,POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),POLYGON EMPTY,MULTIPOINT (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1),MULTIPOINT EMPTY,MULTILINESTRING ((5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9), (5 6, 15 17, 8 9)),MULTILINESTRING EMPTY,MULTIPOLYGON (((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1)),, ((55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1), (55 1, 7 6, 90 99, 33 5, 55 1))),MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY)'
let stringArray = string.split(/(?:\,)(?=[A-Z])/);

console.log(stringArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain how the regular expression works, as I do not understand it fully (I do not know what ?:\ and ?= stand for)

Answer (score 0):

It splits by comma followed by any upper case letter `string.split(/,(?=[A-Z])/)`